# how to create pfx file from private public key?

Tags: openssl

I want to generate pfx file and I have 2 files like this:

```
private.key:
-----------BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----------
CONTAIN
----------END RSA PRIVATE KEY--------------
in public.key:

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----------------
CONTAIN
------END PUBLIC KEY----------------------
```

How can I create a pfx file from these 2 files ?

Thanks

Comment: You do not have a certificate?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553149/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-key-file-to-a-pfx where you will find your solution.